# Docker + Laravel issue [SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution]

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker, docker-compose

I have docker installed on ubuntu machine and I'm trying to run a laravel app.

MySQL service has `service_name: mysql` in docker-compose.yml file and .env file has `DB_HOST=mysql`.

As I remember .env file should figure out that `DB_HOST=mysql` points to the mysql docker service IP. However this isn't happening and after running migrations I get:

> `Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')`

First I ran `docker-compose build`, after which I ran `docker-compose up -d` and all of my 3 services are up and running.

If I extract the IP of MySQL service and use it in `.env` file like this:

`DB_HOST=172.18.0.2`

I can then run migrations successfully and in this case everything works fine.

However, I consider this as bad practice since IP address could be changed if MySQL service is restarted. Am I missing something here, why using `service_name` in my `.env` file for `DB_HOST` fails resolving db host name?

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  laravel:

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - laravel
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports: 
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes: 
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: laraone
      MYSQL_USER: laraone_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
      - laravel
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php
    volumes: 
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - laravel
```

.env:

```
APP_NAME=Laraone
APP_ENV="local"
APP_KEY=base64:PMwGrcSu2ioPEj75dv5gcdWAogESOtt8UCr/gs0nOtw=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost:8080

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laraone
DB_USERNAME=laraone_user
DB_PASSWORD=secret

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=

MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=noreply@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

MAIL_SENDMAIL="/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs"
```

Comment: `DB_HOST=mysql` This should probably be `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. It needs the hostname or IP in order to find the server.

Comment: @aynber That’s wrong in a Docker context: `localhost` is almost always “this container”.  (But if the question is about trying to run migrations from the host with the stack otherwise running in Docker, `localhost` would be right then.)

Comment: @aynber I would disagree with that. `DB_HOST` should be set to `mysql` as that is the service name of the container in the `docker-compose.yml` file. I run a laravel app and that is exactly how it is configured. I feel like something is wrong with the networks but can't see why. What i'd do is `docker-compose exec php bash` and `ping mysql` or `telnet mysql 3306`. You may need to download and install either of those packages within the container.

Comment: @aynber If I use localhost then I get: `Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')` 

If I use 127.0.0.1 migrations are executed without any exceptions and afterwards when I load the app in browser I get 404 on all routes. In this case database host is recognised but not correctly connected to the laravel app.

Comment: Thanks, @leeman24, for the explanation. I use homestead, not Docker, so HOST is localhost or an IP for me. I didn't realize Docker set a mysql hostname.

Comment: @leeman24 I did what you stated above and this is the result: `--- mysql ping statistics ---
63 packets transmitted, 63 received, 0% packet loss, time 486ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.070/0.106/0.472/0.051 ms`
I'm still unsure why mysql container_name doesn't get resolved in env file

Comment: @themystery, Agreed that is odd behaviour. This probably won't help but exec into php and run `echo $DB_HOST`. Maybe your `.env` file is not being applied properly although when you said you changed the value it gave different behaviour.

Comment: @leeman24 Thanks for this advice. I get an odd response when I do `echo $DB_HOST`, I uploaded it from my terminal here > https://prnt.sc/qre0wm
It looks like $DB_HOST doesn't get any value, and I'm still unsure why is this happening

Comment: Actually sorry, that is not necessarily an indication that things are misconfigured. I moved my laravel project to Kubernetes and am defining those as environment variables. Where is that `.env` file? My laravel project running on docker we put it gets mounted under `/var/www/api/.env` where I think you should have it under `/var/www/html/.env` possibly.

Answer (score 10):

I think you try to run "php artisan migrate" command outside php docker container.

You should run php artisan migrate command inside php container.

Try following;

```
docker ps --> list running containers

docker exec -it <your_container_id> bash
```

and now you can run;

```
php artisan migrate
```

Edit:
You can also write artisan command without entering container bash as following;

```
docker exec -i <your_container_id> php artisan migrate
```

Comment: YES. This help me out, I spend whole day to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still wanting a dockerized Laravel enviroment, check out Laravel Sail. It lets you route commands to the docker instance easily with an alias `sail`. Like `sail artisan migrate`.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail

> Laravel Sail is a light-weight command-line interface for interacting
> with Laravel's default Docker development environment. Sail provides a
> great starting point for building a Laravel application using PHP,
> MySQL, and Redis without requiring prior Docker experience.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION 1:

Always run docker ps to check if your ports are well mapped. below you can see what I mean.

[image]

to fix this you need to check if you have another instance of MySQL running with this port number and stop it or try a different port
[image]

SOLUTION 2:

change your credentials to

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

here is mysql yml
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by installing laravel app inside a php container. Simple 1-line command which helped me solve this problem: `docker exec -it php php artisan app:install`

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue, with console command I created, with docker containers to mysql and php
(just entrypoint for dev runnig `php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0`)
and I tried to run on host
`php artisan my:console:command`
which return :
`` SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution (SQL: select * from `mytable` limit 5) ``

By running :
`docker exec -it myPhpContainerName php artisan my:console:command`
it works fine