# How can I run database migrations when using Dusk, Docker, and Laravel?

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-8, laravel-dusk, laravel-migrations

How can I run my Dusk test using Laravel and Docker?

The below solution works when I run migrations from the command line for my test application.

[Docker + Laravel issue [SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59862684/docker-laravel-issue-sqlstatehy000-2002-php-network-getaddresses-getaddr)

I have a .env.dusk with a separate database. when I run `php artisian dusk` I get the below error

`php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution`

How can I get my migrations to work when running dusk?

Thank you